# (ssg-wsg) How to get active subscription to 'Get TSC Details' API?

Tags: api

I want to get access to the SSG-WSG Skills Framework APIs. Most API subscriptions get an  'Active' status in my account. Only the 'Get TSC Details' and 'Get GSC Details' API subscription keep having a 'Pending' Status. How do I get an 'Active' Status for these APIs as well?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the API details: https://developer.ssg-wsg.gov.sg/webapp/docs/product/6Gl44K5M46EuDgn7LCsAs2/group/5uyNzClV5UJk6Uo0wDg7Mt/api/1n1sP9UIv65cLu49s5hy9u/version/1iINOw6C1V8l1r2UVh7r8v

This API requires approval. It should remain pending until it is approved.

API approval process: https://developer.ssg-wsg.gov.sg/webapp/guides/6gvz7gEnwU2dSIKPrTcXnq#3-subscribing-to-ssg-wsg-apis

If you are a corporate developer, you can also reach out to their servicedesk for details: https://developer.ssg-wsg.gov.sg/webapp/faq?anchor=WhoCanIContactIfIHaveQuestionsAboutTheseAPIs